# Using JAVA - How can I compute the total sum of input strings & their lengths without using Array?

Tags: java

I am not getting the correct output... Any help with this function in JAVA?

**The expected Output should be:**

> The total sum of the word lengths entered was: 9 (depending on user
>   input)
>  The longest word was: Oranges, with length 7
>  The
>   shortest word was: Ox, with length 2

**Note:** No Array is to be used. Thanks

---

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    String line;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int count = 0;
    while (!(line = input.nextLine()).isEmpty()) 
    {
      System.out.println("Enter word:  ");
      count++;

    } System.out.println("The total sum of the word lengths entered was: " + count + " words. ");
      System.out.println("The longest word was: " input + " with length " + input.length);
      System.out.println("The shortest word was: " input + " with length " + input.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, check out this link [on topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Not clear why you think you need an array anyway... Where are you checking the word lengths? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String line;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int count = 0;
        String shortest = String.format("%0" + 10000 + "d", 0).replace("0", "x");
        String longest = "";

        while (!(line = input.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {

            System.out.println("Enter word:  ");
            count += line.length();

            if (line.length() > longest.length())
                longest = line;
            if(line.length() < shortest.length())
                shortest = line;
        } 
        System.out.println("The total sum of the word lengths entered was: " + count + " words. ");
        System.out.println("The longest word was: " + longest + " with length " + longest.length());
        System.out.println("The shortest word was: "  + shortest + " with length " + shortest.length());
  }
}
```

Comment: Any alternatives for " StringUtils.repeat("x", 10000); " Shows errors.

Comment: @MrCEO Of course there are many alternatives but, you have said no array! try this: `String shortest = String.format("%0" + 10000 + "d", 0).replace("0", "x");`

Comment: That was very useful addition... Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

In your while block (the lines between the {} pair after `while`), you have the line that someone entered. It is of type String.

If you look up the String class in Java, you will find that it has a method for `length()`, so that's how you get the length of the line (`line.length()` returns an int length).

To track the longest line, you need a variable declared up where `count` is declared that is going to store the longest line entered. For each line, compare the length of the line you have with the longest length you've encountered so far; if the current one is the longest, then store its length (and its value, if you'll need that also, in a variable declared next to count and the longest line value). The reason I'm pointing out where to put them is that they need to be declared outside the while loop so that you can refer to them after the loop has finished.

Shortest is done the same way, with different variables.

Good luck -- post more questions if you need to! I've tried to give you enough info that you can write the actual code yourself, but it's hard to gauge just how much that is.

Comment: Yes, I can see where I missed. I am sure I can apply some new modification to get this working correctly. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Set the smallest and largest word sizes based on the first word encountered. Then keep comparing values to determine the sizes. This also handles case if words are the same size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    int largestSize = 0;
    int smallestSize = 0;
    String longestWord = "";
    String shortestWord = "";

    while (!(line = input.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Enter word:  ");
        count++;

        //Initialize sizes and words on first round.
        if (count == 1) {
            smallestSize = largestSize;
            shortestWord = line;
        }

        //Do the comparisons.
        if (largestSize <= line.length()) {
            largestSize = line.length();
            longestWord = line;
        } else if (smallestSize > line.length()) {
            smallestSize = line.length();
            shortestWord = line;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The total sum of the word lengths entered was: " + count + " words. ");
    System.out.println("The longest word was: " + longestWord + " with length " + longestWord.length());
    System.out.println("The shortest word was: " + shortestWord + " with length " + shortestWord.length());
}
```